# How to take in html a value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i am new in javascript and jquery, i tried many things that is found in site like related questions but i could not solve my problem.

How can i take a value from this piece of html ?

```
<div class="frmPillIdentifier-field-fmt">
 <select id="scolor" name="scolor" size="1">
  <option id="colorOption" value="8">Kirli Beyaz</option>
 </select>
```

How can get a value in option tag?

i tried something like this but it didnt solve my problem :

```
$colorValue = jQuery('#frmPillIdentifier-field-fmt > select[name=scolor] > option[id=colorOption]');
//$colorValue = $('#colorOption').val();
  $shapeValue = $('#shapeOption').val();
  console.log("Renkler"+$colorValue.val()+$shapeValue);
```

Console Error is like this " = Renklerundefinedundefined "

Comment: Do you want the value of the option that's currently selected, or the value of that specific option, no matter what is actually selected?

Comment: I tried it but it doesnt solve my problem

Comment: I want just to get vale inside <option> tag

Comment: Is your code inside `$(document).ready()`?

Comment: Start by opening your console (F12) and check for errors.

Comment: I have spotted a mistake in the code: #frmPillIdentifier-field-fmt instead of .frmPillIdentifier-field-fmt for a class. Either you need to change the class to id in the div tag or you need to change it to a dot instead of hash in jquery. However, this correction still may not fix the issue.

Comment: Just curious, but why do you use `$` in your variable names? This is javascript..

Comment: @alKid It's common to use $ in variables that hold jQuery objects (although `$shapeValue` does hold a string).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the first line to:

```
$colorValue = jQuery('.frmPillIdentifier-field-fmt > select[name=scolor] > option[id=colorOption]');
```

`frmPillIdentifier-field-fmt` is a class, not an ID, so you use `.` to select it.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/x7rjG/1/)

Or you can simply use:

```
$colorValue = $("#colorOption");
```

Since IDs are unique, you don't have to give a detailed path to access it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use for getting value;

```
$("#colorOption").attr("value");
```

Answer (score -1):

use this

```
select = document.getElementById("scolor");
shapeValue=select.value;
```

Comment: Why do you think this will work if the original code didn't?

Answer (score -1):

Enough of this:

```
    <select id="scolor" name="scolor" size="1">
  <option value="_0">--Choose--</option> 
  <option value="_8">Kirli Beyaz</option>
  <option value="_9">Some thing</option>
</select>    


var colorSet = {
 _0: 'data0'
 ,_8: 'data8'
 ,_9: 'data9'
}


var shapeValue = $('#shapeOption').val();
var colorValue = calorSet[ shapeValue]

console.log("Renkler" + colorValue + shapeValue);
```

PS 
You can not duplicate IDs. And without all the variables Var be in the global scope that bad.

Answer (score -1):

Try to Use this code:

```
$('#scolor').change(function(){
    var optionvalue = $("#colorOption option:selected").text();
});
```